# How do I clear the Production floor in Fortune 499

Tags: fortune-499

This is the floor layout and rules of this scenario:

```
+---------+  -|+# walls   
|@#.......|
|.###.###.|     ↓ way out
|..X...X..|
|.###.###.|     @ you (moves cardinally, 1 space per turn)
|.###.###.|
|..X...X..|     X monster (moves cardinally, 1 space per turn towards the player
|.###.###.|                only if @ is in direct line of sight)
|.........|       also, a spawner (if monster is killed and & is alive,
|.........|                        X respawns on the next turn in its original position)
|....&....|
+↓--------+     & summoner (does not move; if dead, spawners stop working;
                            comes back within ? turns unless no X are left)
```

What is the movement strategy you need to clear this level?

Answer (score 3):

The unexplained rule of the puzzle is that if a monster `X` is standing on the spawner `×` (its starting position) when the summoner `&` is defeated, then all monsters will be killed on the same turn (as hinted at the start of the floor).

So the solution becomes merely:

```
(1)            (2)            (3)            (4)           

+---------+    +---------+    +---------+    +---------+   
|@#.......|    |.#.......|    |.#..↓←←←@|    |.#.......|   
|↓###.###.|    |.###.###↑|    |.###↓###.|    |.###.###.|   
|↓.X...X..|    |.X×...X.↑|    |.X×.↓.×X.|    |..X...X..|   
|↓###.###.|    |.###.###↑|    |.###↓###.|    |.###.###.|   
|↓###.###.|    |.###.###↑|    |.###↓###.|    |.###.###.|   
|↓.X...X..|    |.X×...X.↑|    |.X×.↓.×X.|    |..X...X..|   
|↓###.###.|    |.###.###↑|    |.###↓###.|    |.###.###.|   
|.........|    |@→→→→→→→↑|    |....↓....|    |.........|   
|.........|    |.........|    |.........|    |....@....|   
|....&....|    |....&....|    |....&....|    |....&....|   
+.--------+    +.--------+    +.--------+    +.--------+   

Go down the    Then up the    Then down      Fight the     
corridor       corridor       the middle     summoner.
```

This floor is not the end of the level and a number of boss fights come next. If you lost a lot of health on this floor trying to figure a solution out, I would advise you to take an intentional death and $100 hit (or loading from your save file) so you can start the next floor with enough health to win.